# Constantly getting DISCONNECTED message in krunker.io

Tags: krunker.io

Everytime I try to enter on a Krunker.io match to play a game, I get "DISCONNECTED" message. After changing the server a lot of times (that is represented by the `?game=xy:abcde` in Krunker.io url, like `krunker.io/?game=SV:lksfj` for example), it works. But that doesn't make any sense to me. What should I do to stop getting this message and join a match without this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Solution 1*: **disable all your chrome extensions**, in most cases, ad blockers.

*Solution 2*: your **connection to the internet** is **unstable**. Reboot it.

*Solution 3*: install Krunker on **Steam**, and you won't get this error anymore.

[image]
[image]